# Show QGIS layer definition (qlr) filename in my project not the source file it was created from

Tags: qgis, layers, qlr

I have a QGIS project with multiple qlr (layer definition files) in it which all source the same original data but all have different styling, labeling and filters applied. But when I bring these qlr files into my project the filename I get in my 'layers window' is the original source file which they are all sourced from! 
So I have 4 files all named the same. Can I bring in qlr files and preserve the names they have and not display the source file?

Comment: When you created the QLR files, did the original layers have different names?